# How to switch ideology in Civilization 5 Brave New World

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Want to change my ideology to another due to great unhappiness caused by a civilization superior in culture and having another ideology.

What are the steps for switching ideology manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open your ideology screen. If you can switch ideologies, there will be a button at the bottom of that screen that will allow you to do so.

Comment: That's the way to go. However, just as a little note, that should always be your last option if there is no other way. Trying to keep the people happy with luxury goods or buildings usually pays off more.